# How to convert Entrez ids in a large list into gene symbols and replace entrez ids in list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a large list `data` with 300 names.
For eg:

```
dput(data$name1)
c("55024", "29126", "3732", "1960", "79368", "115352", "10875", 
"2530", "348654", "3070", "29969", "9124", "10125", "143686", 
"6504", "25992", "26137")

dput(data$name2)
c("323", "836", "9976", "1407", "1840", "2289", "2317", "2739", 
"8337", "10964", "3572", "3693", "4023", "4058", "124540", "4638", 
"5214", "6238", "8115", "7049", "8459", "10791", "55884", "7494", 
"7535")

df <- as.data.frame(data$name1)
colnames(df)[1] <- "ENTREZ_IDs"

library(clusterProfiler)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
### Convert Entrez to Ensembl ids and Gene names
Ensembl_GeneNames <- bitr(df$ENTREZ_IDs, fromType = "ENTREZID",
                          toType = c("SYMBOL"),
                          OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)
```

This is the output I got:

[image]

Now, I want to replace the ENTREZID of `name1` in the large list `data` with SYMBOL from the above output.

Would like to do this for all names in the large list `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may loop over the `list` and apply the `bitr`

```
out <- lapply(data, \(x) bitr(x, fromType = "ENTREZID",
                          toType = c("SYMBOL"),
                          OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)[['SYMBOL']])
```